# How to modify multiple state inside a class depending on arguement?

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the state of a class depending on what I pass in but I cannot figure out how to pass in the instance variable as a argument and modify it

```
class Foo:
a = 5
b = 6

def addnum(self, instancevar):
    """
    depending on what I pass in the variable in the instance is incremented
    """
    instancevar +=1
    return instancevar

bar = Foo()
bar.addnum(bar.a) #expecting a = 6
bar.addnum(bar.b) #expecting b = 7
```

This gives me what I want but it feels like I am using kwargs for the wrong reason

```
class Foo:
    a = 5
    b = 6

    def add_num(self, **kwargs):
        if 'a' in kwargs:
            self.a += 1
        if 'b' in kwargs:
            self.b += 1


bar = Foo()
print(bar.a) # a= 5
bar.add_num(a='whateverIWant')
print(bar.a) # a= 6
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you

Comment: You can't do this is the way you imagine. You probably just want to pass a string with the name of the variable (`bar.add_num('a')`)

Comment: Also, _why_ do you want to do this? Is it just for the knowledge? Or to you have a deeper goal that you are 'hiding'? (That goal may have a different better solution)

Comment: Not elite enough to figure out what evil purpose I could use it for, nor do I want to use it with any evil intentions to sabotage my own code. I am just trying to figure the ins and outs of how to use python.

It may seem like I'm trying to break a programming paradigm by accessing "private" variables outside of the class. But aren't all variables practically public like javascript unless defined otherwise?

Comment: (Incidentally, this wouldn't have worked in Javascript either.)

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables are like normal variables, except that you need to prefix them with their instance `instance.attribute`.

You can use them as normal and perform operations on them like normal variables. There's no need to make a function to do this:

```
bar = Foo()
print(bar.a) # --> 5
bar.a += 1 
# add 1 to the bar.a attribute
print(bar.a) # --> 6
```

From your example, you add 1 to both `bar.a` and `bar.b`. If you want to delve deeper into OOP, then you could experiment with operator overloading. This means the use of defining special methods (like `__add__` and `__len__`) to implement custom behaviour and make objects act more like built-in types like `int`.

```
class Foo()
    def __init__(self, a=5, b=6):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (float, int)):
            return Foo(self.a + other,
                       self.b + other)
        elif isinstance(other, Foo):
            return Foo(self.a + other.a,
                    self.b + other.b)
        else:
            raise NotImplemented
```

The `__init__` method is called each time you make a `Foo` instance. `self.a` and `self.b` are instance variables that are unique per instance and changing one does not take affect across all instances, just the one whose value was changed. 
The special method `__add__` is called when I do `Foo() + other` where `Foo()` can be any instance of the class. I've performed a check to see if the other value is a number, and if so it will add it to the `a` and `b` attributes. If the other value is also an instance of `Foo`, then it will add the corresponding 2 `a` values and 2 `b` values together. Each type described here returns a new `Foo` instance. Example:

```
x = Foo(2, 7)
y = Foo(3, 3)

z = x + 5
print(z.a, z.b) # --> 7 and 12
# since it added 5 to x.a and x.b

w = x + y
print(w.a, w.b) # --> 5 and 10
# added x.a to y.a and x.b to y.b

print(x.a, x.b, y.a, y.b) 
# --> 2, 7, 3, 3 (the original instances are unaffected)
```

Comment: Now I understand. 
I can edit the variable from the outside instead of trying to make the manipulate the code from the inside.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: _this modifies the 'a' attribute of **all** instances_ False. It creates a new attribute 'a' for the instance but does neither modify the class attribute nor the attribute of other instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could do pass the *name* of the variable, and do something like this

```
def addnum(self, var_name):
    setattr(self, var_name, getattr(self, var_name) + 1)
```